# Weird new instance creation syntax behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-debugging

I have declared a property to capture the querystring of the current page. I also have a class that has same property name as the querystring variable. Below are my debug environment,

```
   private Guid? ParishId
    {
        get
        {
            Guid guid;
            if (Guid.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out guid))
            {
                return guid;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is what I expect the `p.ParishId` to have, This I got when I inspect the `p` object

[image]

But it's showing the value of the querystring variable. This I got placing mouse on ParishId

[image]

Why is it not seeing the newly assigned Guid?

Comment: Have you tried changing the private to public and seeing if it shows up in the Debugger

Comment: @DJKRAZE I meant that the value of `p.ParishId` within the curly brace is reflecting the value of the QueryString instead of the new Guid I assigned to it. The ParishId for querystring is fine. Inspecting object `p` shows the right value, but inspecing `ParishId` within the curly braces shows the querystring value

Comment: Debugger works slightly differently. When you move the mouse over identifier it will evaluate it based on the current scope. The only `ParishId` in the current scope is the property of the class that obtains it from `QueryString`.

Comment: @codingbiz sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

Debugger invokes the property of the instance you are currently in - according to the current scope. `p.ParishId` - is the property of instance `p`, `ParishId` - is the property of whatever happens to be the scope, which in your case is the class that obtains the value from `QueryString`.

**Update:**

I am not sure what reference you want. When you move the mouse over an identifier, the debugger does the same thing that is done when you add that identifier to Watches list, i.e. resolves it in the current scope. The C# capability to assign fields/properties of an instance at the moment of creation is just language syntactic sugar. To inspect `ParishId` property of instance `p`, you need to evaluate `p.ParishId` or to be inside code of `p` class.

Comment: Can you please post a reference link to confirm your answer?

Comment: @codingbiz - what, you don't believe me :) ? See an update to my answer.